# How to setup up Labview/myRIO to communicate via UART

Tags: asynchronous, sensors, uart, labview

I'm trying to write to, and read a 3-Space Sensor Nano from a NI myRIO/Labview via UART (or I2C, or SPI - just messing around with them). I have about 0 experience with sending commands via bytes.

I've read through the documentation and understand that I need to initialize the process with the first byte and then send some commands. Then, hopefully, the sensor spits back what I want.

[This is the documentation for the sensor.](https://yostlabs.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/pdf/3-Space-Sensor-Users-Manual-Nano.pdf) Page 24-25 is what I believe I should be sending.

[This is the block diagram of what I've tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k68Q.jpg) Honestly, I have no clue what I'm doing and couldn't find any good examples online.

If someone could point me in the right direction, or to some resources where I can learn more, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your sensor. You can send it ASCII commands like the examples on page 25:

```
:0\n
```

This would request the orientation to your sensor.

For the LabVIEW part you can start with [this example](http://www.ni.com/example/27669/en/).

I strongly advise you to make sure you have the right connections and the signal levels on your RIO agree with those your sensor need. If you have a RS232 RIO unit (NI-9870), note that you will need to add a MAX232 level shifter (see page 20 on your sensor manual).

Comment: I switched to using the ASCII commands and still no luck.

[Similarly, i tried using the I2C connection but I'm still lost.](https://imgur.com/a/5P58HuD) 

I'm quite confident that my wiring is correct.

Comment: It's been a while since I used NI products. Do they show as COM ports that you can access them from Windows outside of LabVIEW? If so you can try with a terminal like RealTerm or PuTTY and send the ASCII commands from there?

Comment: By the way, how are you wiring to the serial port for the I2C bus? or you're using a different module on the RIO for that? One thing I noticed from the manual is that no matter what bus you use you need to supply it with external power (from a 3.3 to 6 V supply) apparently. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Ultimately I need to use Labview to collect data from other sensors so I'd rather figure it out on there. 

I'm using pins 32 (SCL), 34 (SDA), 32 (GND), 33 (+3.3V). Then i have the data cable and the power cable plugged into the myrio

Comment: I see... Maybe you need a way to make sure the port is working properly from LabVIEW, like a [loopback test](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3450/en/). I think you might be a bit overconfident with your wiring. A TTL UART, RS232, SPI and I2C are all different beasts, you cannot simply connect them together. If you edit your question with details on how you are doing the wiring I might be able to help. LabVIEW is also quite picky so if I were you I would rather start making sure the you can establish a connection with a native or virtual serial port and PuTTY if you have one available

Comment: [so I've kinda figured it out using SPI](https://imgur.com/a/Y5yxy6a) but im having trouble processing the read values. Every output is 255. I think I'll open a new thread.

Comment: OK, great. Be sure to explain your setup in detail.